# When will a new array be created when I use the slice operator in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Today, when I used the slice operator to modify an array, I found that the following operations got different results, although operations seemed to be the same.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,5,4],[4,5,3],[5,8,7]])
print(a)
a[[0,1],:][0:2,:] = [[11,12,13],[8,9,7]]
print(a)
a[0:2,:][[0,1],:] = [[11,12,13],[8,9,7]]
print(a)
```

the results are following:

```
[[1 2 3]
[0 5 4]
[4 5 3]
[5 8 7]]

[[1 2 3]
[0 5 4]
[4 5 3]
[5 8 7]]

[[11 12 13]
[8 9 7]
[4 5 3]
[5 8 7]]
```

I guess that "a[[0,1],:]" creates a new array, and "a[0:2,:]" doesn't. But why? I am confused. I want to know under what conditions a new array will be created when I use the slice operator.

Comment: I agree it's confusing…this is worth reading: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[[0,1],:]` with a list is "advanced indexing".  It makes a copy.  The `[0,1]` is not a slice.

`a[0:2,:]` with a slice is "basic indexing".  It returns a `view`.

`a[[0,1],:][0:2,:] = ...` tries to modify that copy, and doesn't affect `a`. `a[0:2,:][[0,1],:] = ...` tries to modify the `view`, and thus also modifies `a`.

`a[[0,1],:] = ...` will successfully modify `a`.

It's a good idea of avoid the the indexing sequence when setting values.  `a[...][...] = ...`.  As this example shows, sometimes it works, other times not.  If you avoid it entirely you won't have to worry about which works.

Even when fetching values the double indexing is less than ideal.  It always works, but can be harder to understand.

```
a[0:2,:][[0,1],:] = [[11,12,13],[8,9,7]]
```

is evaluated as

```
a.__getitem__((slice(0,2), slice(None))).
  __setitem__(([0,1], slice(None)), [[11,12,13],[8,9,7] )
```

The `getitem` is performed first, and the `setitem` is applied to that result.  So when chaining indexing it is crucial that you understand what that first indexing does.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. You said that a[[0,1],:] makes a copy, but a[[0,1],:] = ...  will successfully modify a. How to understand this point? If a[[0,1],:] makes a copy, a[[0,1],:] = ... should not modify a. Could you give me more explanation? Thank you very much.

Comment: One is in a getitem, the other a setitem.  I believe the `advanced indexing section is clear on this.

Comment: the view versus copy distinction does not apply in an assignment, `x[...]= ...`

Comment: I guess I understand the difference between `a[[0,1],:]` and `a[0:2,:]`. `a[[0,1],:]` is a **fancy indexing**, and it does not return views. But if I use `a[[0,1],:] = ... ` directly, it is **lvalue indexing** (i.e. the indices are placed in the left-hand side value of an assignment) and no view or copy of the array is created (because there is no need to), so I will get the same result when I use `a[[0,1],:]=...` and `a[0:2,:]=...`. However, `a[0:2,:]` always returns views.

Comment: `a[[0,1],:][0:2,:] = ...` is equal to two steps: `a1 = a[[0,1],:]` and `a1[0:2,:] = ... `. `a[0:2,:][[0,1],:] = ...` is also equal to two steps: `a2 = [0:2,:]`  and `a2[[0,1],:] = ... `. `a1` is the copy of `a`, but `a2` is the view of `a`.